# Make AutoMapper's IMapper.Map ignore any properties not POSTed per an httpcontext request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am POSTing an update to an entity using a method with a `modelDTO` parameter. I use entity framework to get the relevant `entity` object. Next I use IMapper.Map(modelDTO, entity) to update the entity. The problem I have is that if the particular view that was used to generate the POST didn't include some of the model's properties in the `<form>` then automapper will reset the properties on the entity to the default. I want to avoid creating lots of similar DTOs for each of my different views since they're virtually the same. I also can't just tell auto mapper to ignore default values since sometimes that's what the user wants to change things to.

I was thinking, is there a way to pass an httpcontext in the `Map` function, and configure somewhere the logic to look at what's been POSTed to determine whether or not to overwrite the destination or not?

Comment: It seems that you need to write a custom method to realize the auto map feature, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what you mean. I guess I will have to create something to do what I want. My question is what AutoMapper API can I use.